Requesting explanation on the meaning of the word 'Passerby'?
Merriam-Webster defines it as:
"One who passes by"
Similarly, Cambridge defines it as:
"someone who is going past a particular place"
Now, in a particular situation, where a person, let's say John, is walking on the road and encounters many people, some going in his direction, while other in his opposite direction.
The question: Do those both kinds of people qualify as passerby(passerbys?)? And what would be better terms to refer to them distinctly?
"John was greeted by many of the people passing by."
"John was greeted by many of the people he came across on his way home."
In those sentences, when read individually, is the distinction between the two kinds clear?

Note that the plural of passerby is the irregular (but more logical) passersby.

I always hyphenate it: passer-by, passers-by.

Is "passerby" related to "hereby" but from more personal/subjective viewpoint, like a passenger, outlander, or stranger? You may also consult history of band Flyleaf who was previously known as Passerby (around 2002 on records): https://www.discogs.com/release/6216642-Passerby-Broken-Wings-EP

Passer-by

a person that is passing or going by, esp on foot


He likes to walk the streets, observing passers-by and engaging them in conversation.
The Guardian (2018)

In the OP’s example, both groups of people passed by John and hence can be considered passers-by.  We can describe the situation more clearly in just a few more words:
John was greeted by many passers-by going in the same (or opposite) direction.
John was greeted by many passers-by going in both directions.

(FWIW, I much prefer the hyphenated form, as it's much easier to recognise and removes the ambiguity over pronunciation.  Otherwise I'd want to pronounce it to rhyme with ‘Appleby’ or ‘Wetherby’, and then have to stop and correct it.  A hyphen also makes the plural — passers-by — more natural.)

Thanks, @gidds.  Agreed. Indeed the hyphenated forms were more common for a long time until recent decades, especially the plural one.  They are still more widely used than the unhyphenated ones in BrE.

I also agree with the hyphenated form. "Passerby" doesn't look like a real word to me.

Thanks, @Chris Melville.  The hyphenated form is my preference.   gidds said it well, that it helps people place correctly the s morpheme.

In general, we say "passerby" to mean someone passing by some specific place. (And side note, the technically correct plural is "passersby", but many English speakers say "passerbys".)
So you might say, "Many passersby admired the fine architecture of the building", or, "When John had a heart attack, a passerby stopped and helped get him to the hospital."
I'm not sure if there's any rule against using the word to describe people met by someone who is moving. But if you did use the word this way, like, "As I walked down Water Street, I met many passersby", we do not make any distinction between people going the same direction as you and people going the opposite direction. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that you would use "passerby" for people that one meets going in the same direction and "people he came across" for people one meets going in the opposite direction. Or maybe you're thinking the other way around. Either way, no. No fluent English speaker would understand either term to be limited to people going in one particular direction. If you want to make that distinction, you'd have to add more words. Like, "He met people going in the same direction and people going in the opposite direction." Hey, you might need to distinguish three cases: people you meet coming in the opposite direction, people you pass going in the same direction, and people who pass you going in the same direction. Assuming this distinction matters in context.

Just a point of clarification.   All that is necessary for the meaning is a location and people walking past it. A second person somehow linked with the location is unnecessary but certainly possible.

The bar of gold bullion lay on the sidewalk all morning and not a single passerby stooped to pick it up.
John sat on his front stoop talking like a pirate. All the passersby gave him a wide berth.


+1 This is the correct way to define a passers-by - All that is necessary for the meaning is a location and people walking past it.

When the word passerby refers to people, it is used by an observer who is at a fixed point - like sitting at a cafe table - seeing people go by: the passersby.
If you are walking down a road, the people you pass would not be passersby.
So, to answer the question, here people passing by can be used if John is at fixed place: "John was greeted by many of the passersby or by those passing by." In any case, in this example,  If John stays in a particular place and is not moving, either can be used.
If John is moving, those he runs into and who greet him are those he runs into or  comes across on his way home. They are not, however, passersby as he is moving.
In other words, passerby implies an observer of a scene from a fixed point.

If you are walking down a road, the people you pass would not be passersby. - Which dictionary says so ??

@JamesMathai It's called a semantic trait. passerby is someone who passes by you when you are at some point, not usually while you walking.

Physics-ally speaking, at the moment of passing, you are at a fixed point.

@mcalex Really? Not in a regular world. We're not in a Schrodinger's cat world here. We'd say: physics-wise, by the way.
